# USB device showing 'Insert a disk' message

Tags: windows-10, usb, external-hard-drive, diskpart, disk-management

Here is the story. I got this usb today and I did format it with default settings (only changed its name). Then I copied some files into my usb. Without ejecting it (I think), I disconnected the usb. A few hours later I plugged in my usb and windows said something like "There is a error with you device. Click here if you wanna fix it" and I ignored that message. After a few seconds usb device disappeared and it's not working anymore. The device shows up in device manager but shows 0 in disk manager.
I tried `diskpart` method that was interduced in many websites but I got this error:
[image]

and this is the warning message shown by event viewer:

```
Log Name:      Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-PnP/Configuration
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-PnP
Date:          3/24/2022 10:16:06 AM
Event ID:      442
Task Category: None
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      DESKTOP-GF8HPVQ
Description:
Device USBSTOR\Disk&Ven_Generic&Prod_USB_Flash_Disk&Rev_7.76\6&30cec419&0 was not migrated due to partial or ambiguous match.

Last Device Instance Id: USBSTOR\Disk&Ven_Philips&Prod_USB_Flash_Drive&Rev_PMAP\070827BB1F196669&0
Class Guid: {4d36e967-e325-11ce-bfc1-08002be10318}
Location Path: 
Migration Rank: 0xF000FC000000F130
Present: false
Status: 0xC0000719
```

and this is how the usb is visible in disk manager and this pc:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Flash memory devices often die spontaneously and without and warning.

Comment: If we were to focus just on the part where "Insert a disk" message is being shown, It is a general indication of hardware failure (Source of this claim being my personal experience).

Answer (score 1):

In Disk Management, right-click the disk and then click "Initialize Disk"
(if you have that option).
If the disk is listed as Offline, first right-click it and select "Online"
and then format it.

If none of these options is available or don't work, then the disk is dead.